# Limit of $ \frac{f(x) f''(x)}{(f'(x))^{2}}$ at $\alpha$ with $f(\alpha)= f'(\alpha)= f''(\alpha)=0$ and $f'''(\alpha) \not= 0$ via L'hopital

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, newton-raphson

Suppose $f$ is a $C^{4}$ function with $f(\alpha)= f'(\alpha)= f''(\alpha)=0$ and $f'''(\alpha) \not= 0$.
I wish to compute the following limit:

> $$ \lim_{x \to \alpha} \frac{f(x) f''(x)}{(f'(x))^{2}}.$$

The result I get by repeatedly applying L'hopital is $\frac{1}{2}$, but if I assume $f \in C^{5}$ I am able to compute $\frac{2}{3}$.

Which one is the right value?

Comment: it would help to see your logic

Comment: $$\lim_{x\to\alpha}\frac{f(x)f''(x)}{[f'(x)]^2}=\lim_{x\to\alpha}\frac{f'(x)f''(x)+f(x)f'''(x)}{2f'(x)f''(x)}=\lim_{x\to\alpha}\frac{[f''(x)]^2+2f'(x)f'''(x)+f(x)f''''(x)}{2[f''(x)]^2+2f'(x)f'''(x)}$$ How far did you have to go to get this answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Taylor expansion here.
$$
f(x)=f'''(\alpha)(x-\alpha)^3/6+o(x-\alpha)^3,
$$
$$
f'(x)=f'''(\alpha)(x-\alpha)^2/2+o(x-\alpha)^2
$$
and 
$$
f''(x)=f'''(\alpha)(x-\alpha)+o(x-\alpha)
$$
Just replace everything by its expansion and you get $2/3$.

Comment: Great! So I assume this doesn't require $f \in C^{5}$? I can't see how it would, but just double checking!

Comment: No, it does not. Local Taylor expansions only require the existence of the highest derivative at the given point (the center of the expansion). Of course this requires all the lower derivatives to exist in some neighborhood. In this case, we only need the existence of $f'''(\alpha)$.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!!!